# Passing screen-defined function to header triggering "Non-serializable" issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a stack navigator in which one of my screens, I have defined the global header bar to contain a button that will trigger a modal. The issue I have is that I am defining the function to trigger said modal from within the screen component itself and attempting to pass the function via `navigation.setParams` and I am facing the warning:

> Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state

```
const ViewB = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({showModal: () => setShowModal(true)});
  }, []);
```

```
<Stack.Screen name="ViewB" component={ViewB} options={({ route }) => ({
  headerRight: () => (
      <View>
          <Button onPress={() => {
              showModal = route?.params?.["showModal"];
              showModal && showModal();
          }} title="Toggle modal" />
      </View>
  )
})} />
```

After Googling I did come across the [official docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state) on the issue and also [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66326864/3061047) that explained that RN doesn't like us passing functions to `navigation` as it could potentially break functionality down the line if things change etc... however I'm unsure of a better way to go about this.

Is there a way in which I can achieve my desired result without upsetting react-native?

**[Here is a stack with my example](https://snack.expo.dev/@physicsboy/modal-from-stack-header)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **react-navigation doesn't allow us to pass the methods in navigation** props.

As per your requirement there is no need to pass the method in the params to the parent.

you can **achieve this by adding the headerRight inside your screen code**, checkout the below code changes for better understanding.

```
const ViewB = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <View>
          <Button
            onPress={() => {
              setShowModal(true);
            }}
            title="Toggle modal"
          />
        </View>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  const onBackPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate(route.params.previousScreen, {
      val: 5,
      val2: 6,
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>ViewB</Text>
      <Text>Params: {JSON.stringify(route.params)}</Text>
      <Button title="back" onPress={onBackPress} />
      {showModal && <Modal onClose={() => setShowModal(false)} />}
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
        <Stack.Screen name="ViewA" component={ViewA} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ViewB" component={ViewB} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant. I'm still learning RN and did think of something along this lines, just didn't know how to implement. Cheers :-)